# Hudson: developing plugin but it's not appearing on my main page?

Tags: hudson-plugins, jenkins

I'm trying to add a link to the main page of my jenkins.
After looking through some examples (I'm new at developing Jenkins plugins), it seems I just need to create a class that extends Notifier (you don't seem to need to define it anywhere else?) and override the perform step.

I tried both :

```
@Override
    public boolean perform(AbstractBuild<?, ?> build, Launcher launcher, BuildListener listener) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        List<Action> installedActions = Hudson.getInstance().getActions();
                BuildMonitorAction action = new BuildMonitorAction();
                if(!installedActions.contains(action)){
                        Hudson.getInstance().getActions().add(action);
                }

        return true;
}
```

And:

```
@Override
    public boolean perform(AbstractBuild<?, ?> build, Launcher launcher, BuildListener listener) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        List<Action> installedActions = Hudson.getInstance().getActions();
        for (Action installedAction: installedActions) {
            if (installedAction instanceof BuildMonitorAction) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        BuildMonitorAction action = new BuildMonitorAction();
        Hudson.getInstance().getActions().add(action);
        return true;
    }
```

But the perform action does not seem to be performed?

The BuildMonitorAction is just:

```
@ExportedBean (defaultVisibility = 999)
@Extension
public class BuildMonitorAction implements RootAction {

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return "grass is green";
    }

    public String getIconFileName() {
        return null;
    }

    public String getUrlName() {
        return "/buildmonitor";
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any pointers as to why a link with display text "grass is green" isn't appearing in my main menu?

And another question: is there a way to clear the jenkins development workspace besides deleting it in my project folder?
mvn clean doesn't seem to clear it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if anyone's looking for this anymore, but apparently having getIconFileName return null will hide the task from showing in your task bar:

http://hudson-ci.org/javadoc/hudson/model/Action.html#getIconFileName%28%29

I just had the method return a random string and it worked. (just the text showed, no broken image or anything)